# Searching from beginning of a list and end of a list (Java)

Tags: java, list

I am confused on how to search from the beginning of the list or from the end of the list.

EDIT: This is code have over 200 lines so if you need anything else please ask. I have added the Node class.

Return node number k.Precondition: 0 <= k < size of the list. If k is 0, return first node; if k = 1, return second node, ...

```
public Node getNode(int k) {
    //TODO 4. This method should take time proportional to min(k, size-k).
    // For example, if k <= size/2, search from the beginning of the
    // list, otherwise search from the end of the list.

    if (k <= size/2) {

    }else {

    }
    return null;
}
public class Node {
    private Node prev; // Previous node on list (null if this is first node)
    private E val;     // The value of this element
    private Node next; // Next node on list. (null if this is last node)

    /** Constructor: an instance with previous node p (can be null),
     * value v, and next node n (can be null). */
    Node(Node p, E v, Node n) {
        prev= p;
        val= v;
        next= n;
    }

    /** Return the node previous to this one (null if this is the
     * first node of the list). */
    public Node prev() {
        return prev;
    }

    /** Return the value of this node. */
    public E value() {
        return val;
    }

    /** Return the next node in this list (null if this is the
     * last node of this list). */
    public Node next() {
        return next;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What is `Node`?  A doubly-linked list?  If so, how would you normally go about getting the kth item?

Comment: `ArrayList.get(k);`

Comment: You haven’t provided the structure of `YourList`, so we have no idea how to find even the first or last `Node` in the list.  You haven’t provided the structure of `Node`, so we have no idea how to navigate from one `Node` to another, in either direction.  Nor have you attempted your own solution. Not sure what help you expect to find here.  We are not clairvoyant.  Without any additional information, your question get closed as unclear or off topic.

Comment: Just who’s question is this?  TempCode’s or JCoding’s???

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually need to search through a list rather than just returning `myNodeList.get(k)`then see below:

Take a look at a normal loop:

```
for (int index=0; index < size; index++) {
            //do something
        }
```

That loop starts at index 0 (`index=0`), it finishes once index is greater than size (`index < size`), and increases each loop (`index++`), but we could easily modify it to start at the maximum size/end `index=size-1`, to finish at 0 (`index >= 0`), and decrease each loop (`index--`).

So from beginning:

```
for (int index=0; index < myNodeList.size(); index++) {
            //do something
        }
```

From end:

```
for (int index=size-1; index >= 0; index--) {
            //do something
        }
```